# ransack search # rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

When I am searching for gender field say "male", it searches for "male" and "female" as "male" keywork is in "female" too.

So How can I use **ransack** in rails so that it matches for exact keyword instead of any partial group of chars.

PS:similarly how can I enable or disable the exact or partial key match in RANSACK gem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could just do

`<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
<%= f.label :gender_eq, "Gender:" %>
<%= f.search_field :gender_eq %>
<% end %>`

that will tell the search to look for the exact string of your input

Here is some of the info from the developer on how it's used.

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#in-your-view

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way you do your search is `<%= (field_name)_cont ... %>` cont means contains.

What you want is `_eq`, change your view into `<%= (field_name)_eq ... %>` and it should work.

For more info:
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching